# Getting libsystemd.so.0 for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, systemd

I am trying to install [Dragonfly](https://www.theobjects.com/dragonfly/) on Ubuntu 14.04. After working out several other issues with the installation, I am now dealing with the problem that I need to get libsystemd.so.0. Based both on the name and on threads from other help communities, I thought I would get it if I installed systemd. However, that does not seem to be the case. I ran `sudo updatedb` and then `locate libsystemd.so.0` and it returned nothing. Is there a step I am missing or did I install the completely wrong package?

---

Edit:

I just ended up installing on a Windows instead. Would have been nice if the docs told you 14.04 and earlier aren't supported. All it says is you need 64-bit Linux.

Comment: No official package provides that file for 14.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libsystemd.so.0

Comment: @muru So is there some unofficial way to get it then? The software won't run without the package.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ships systemd 204, which is a *fairly old* version or systemd.

That version did already have a separate library akin to `libsystemd.so.0`, only it was called `libsystemd-daemon.so.0`.

You can try to install the development files for it (`apt-get install libsystemd-daemon-dev`) and either adapt Dragonfly to try to link against that library, or maybe even try something more hacky and create a symlink `libsystemd.so` pointing to the existing `libsystemd-daemon.so` in your lib directory, maybe Dragonfly will build and work that way, but at this point you have basically "voided the warranty", so even if this works, I wouldn't really recommend it.

If you have a chance to use more recent versions of Ubuntu instead, such as 16.04 LTS or 18.04 LTS, both of those ship more modern versions of systemd which include `libsystemd.so.0`, so I'd expect they'd work fine with the software you're trying to use. If using one of those is an option for you, I'd recommend going that route.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would prefer not to have to change Ubuntu versions but I definitely don't want to "void the warranty" as you put it. Its too bad you can't just copy `libsystemd.so.0` and have it work.

Comment: Since installing system didn't help, is it safe to uninstall it?